# Solving ODE using Laplace transform

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform

> [image]

I am not able to get: Can you find $y(t)?$

I got $$Y(s) = \left( \frac{1}{s} + c \frac{\exp(\frac{-s^2}{2})}{s} \right)$$ I know very well that inverse laplace of $\frac{1}{s}$ is $1$, and also inverse laplace of $c.F(s)$ is $c \text{ inverse laplace of }f(s)$, where $F(s)$ is that part. Now, I am left over with that part which is killing me, I tried to use convolution method considering $\exp(\frac{-s^2}{2})$ ans $\frac{1}{s}$ as two separate functions $F(s)$ and $G(s)$ respectively, however when I am calculating the convolution of those two functions, I am not able to perform it.

Can someone please help me on this? Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Take a look at https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3073608

Comment: @Jean Marie My these is an Airy function connection as $y''-xy=0$ is the Airy equation.

Answer (score 1):

$$y''(t)-ty(t)=0 \implies  Ly''(t)-L(xy(t))=0 \implies s^2Y(s)-sy(0)-y'(0)+Y'(s)=0$$
We get $$Y'(s)+s^2 Y(s)=s \implies y(s)= e^{-s^3/3} \int s e^{s^3/3} ds +C e^{-s^3/3}.$$ Here $e^{s^3/3}$ is the integrating factor,
$$\implies Y(s)= \frac{1}{3^{1/3}} \Gamma[2/3,-s^3/3] e^{-s^3/3}+Ce^{-s^3/3}.$$ So the final solution of the ODE will be given by
$$y(t)=L^{-1}[Y(s)],$$ which does not seem to be available.

I guess that there may be an Airy function connection as $y''-xy=0$ is the Airy equation. Iss solulion is $y(t)=C_1 Ai(t)+ C_2 Bi(t)$

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Airy_function

Comment: It is not surprizing that a special function hasn't an explicit representation, unless one uses an integral form, as asked in the exercice.

Comment: @Jean Marie,there may be an Airy function connection as $y''-xy=0$ is the Airy equation.

Comment: The equation which you wrote is wrong, it is y''-ty = 0, not y'. Hence, if you solve it, you will get the equation in terms of Y(s) as (1/s+c*exp(-s^2/s)/s). Also, we need to use IF (integrating factor) to solve this ODE.

Comment: @Ashis Jana Oh! now I have made corrections.

Comment: I appreciate you for helping me, but its not possible to solve this in this way, you need to use series solutions technique to solve this. I already did and it worked. Use the general form y(t) = sum(a_n.x^n) where n is from 0 to infinity. Then, find y',y'' and put those values in the main equation and solve accordingly. You will get an equation of the form y(t) = a_0*y1(t)+a_1*y2(t), from the initial conditions we know that y(0) = 1 = a_o and y'(0) = 0 = a_1. Therefore, a_1 terms will be 0 and you will basically get y(t) = [1+t^3/6+t^6/180+t^9/(180*72)+....]. Thanks!!

Comment: @Ashis Jana I have added something more now.

Comment: Your laplace equation is wrong sir, L[t.y(t)] is -d/ds[L(y(t)], which means its equal to -d/ds*(s.Y(s)-y(0)). Please check the theorem: Let F(s) be the Laplace transform of f(t). Then, d/ds[F(s)] = −L[tf(t)](s)
or
−d/ds[F(s)] = L[tf(t)](s). That's why you were getting an error. Anyway I got this problem. Thanks for your help. :)

Comment: @AShis Jana Very good.

Answer (score 0):

From $y''-t y=0$ with initial conditions, we get

$$
s^2Y(s)+Y'(s)=s 
$$

which is a linear DE. Solving for the homogeneous easily we obtain

$$
Y_h(s) = C_0 e^{-\frac{s^3}{3}}
$$

for the particular we make $Y_p(s) = C_0(s) e^{-\frac{s^3}{3}}$ and after substitution into the complete DE we have

$$
C'_0(s) = s  e^{\frac{s^3}{3}}
$$

which after integration gives a special function

$$
C_0(s) = -\frac{\Gamma \left(\frac{2}{3},-\frac{s^3}{3}\right)}{\sqrt[3]{3}}
$$

so the solution is

$$
Y(s) = Y_h + Y_p = \left( C_0 -\frac{\Gamma \left(\frac{2}{3},-\frac{s^3}{3}\right)}{\sqrt[3]{3}}\right)e^{-\frac{s^3}{3}}
$$

Now if $Y(s)$ were expandable in series like $Y(s) = \sum_k \frac{a_k}{s^k}$ we could obtain a temporal series representation for $y(t)$ after inversion.

Comment: You don't need to define Y(s) as that, its already defined that y(t) is the solution of the equation Y(s), hence you directly define or let y(t) = sum(a_n*x^n) where n = 0 to infinity, and then proceed accordingly to get y(t) = a_0*y1(t)+a_1*y2(t), from the initial conditions we know that y(0) = 1 = a_o and y'(0) = 0 = a_1. Therefore, a_1 terms will be 0 and you will basically get y(t) =  [1+t^3/6+t^6/180+t^9/(180*72)+....].

Comment: Of course with series you can solve it! The proposed question cites explicitly to do that using the Laplace transform. That is the question! By the way: the attempt to get the Laplace transform in your OP is wrong.

Comment: Hmm got it. Anyway I solved it using series solution technique. Without it, I guess it’s nearly impossible to solve this equation.

Comment: With the Airy functions, the precise solution is $$ y(t) = \frac{1}{2} \left(3^{2/3} \Gamma \left(\frac{2}{3}\right) \text{Ai}(t)+\sqrt[6]{3} \Gamma \left(\frac{2}{3}\right)
   \text{Bi}(t)\right)$$